# SSRS get the last row on each page

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

In SQL Server Reporting Services I have a row group with a dashed bottom border separating each row. I want to remove that dashed border from the last row on each page. How do I calculate the last row on each page?

I counted 25 rows on the first page, so I tried this:

```
iif((rownumber(nothing) MOD 25)=0,nothing,"Dotted")
```

But on page 2 some rows had so much text in a column that in the end the page only had 24 rows, so the row number changes based on amount of text.  I need a new approach. Has anyone had experience with this kind of issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just present a row grouping and then determine the properties on that?  Choose the details row and then select 'Row Groups' and choose 'Add Group'>'Parent Group'.  Define your logic for getting a total, add a footer if you want it at the bottom.  Choose 'Page Breaks' and then report will break on grouping for a new page.  Address the properties for the footers.

Comment: I'm making a conference guest list, so my dataset is a list of {GuestName,Title,Company}. I already have a row grouping, grouped by name. There is about 6 pages of rows. I'm just trying to get the last row on each of those pages.

Comment: You can always add another grouping to existing groupings.  There is not a limitation on groupings in SSRS that I have encountered.  I would just deem it easier to find the end row this way.  Else you could put a line object in a footer and have that intersect the bottom of your table or matrix and that may solve the problem as footers can choose to be repeated on each page.